# I don't want to pay for a work social event, how should I respond if asked why I declined?

Tags: company-culture, socializing

My company wants to hold its first ever social event over the weekend at someone's house. At first I accepted the invitation, although I wasn't at all into it, but then **I learned that all the costs for this event will be split over all attendees**. It's not like a 5$-10$ thing, this would be equivalent to one or two days' work for me. I'm also budgeting and taking care of my ill Mom, so every penny counts. I'm not a cheap person, but this expense is a lot for me. So, I declined the event.

I expect people  (including my manager) will be asking me why I declined. I don't want to lie and say "I have another thing scheduled". I want to make it known that I don't like to be forced to attend and also pay for it. However, I would like to say that in a professional way. I love my job and do many things free of charge, just because I want my company to be a leader in our field.

**How should I respond if asked about this? How can I professionally convey that I don't want to pay for social events?**

Comment: OP, could you add your location (country/state) if you don't mind sharing that info?

Comment: Is this "the company" as in general management inviting all of you to the social event, or "the company" as in the people working there deciding to have a social event?

Comment: @Hilmar I'm not in the US. The $ equivalent of 1 day of work where I live is about 80$. It is a whole day event plus they are doing some activities that need money.

Comment: @DoritoStyle my manager is the one who proposed the idea as a "team building" thing. He hasn't contacted me yet.

Comment: @Haitham thanks, it may help to edit the question  to change "company" to "manager" in the first line, that clears things up slightly. I'm still not 100% sure he would ask but it's a more reasonable assumption if it's "his" event.

Comment: As a side note, even if you could afford it, would you still go? Not wanting to go under any circumstance is different than not wanting to go because of a set budget.

Answer (score 200):

Be honest about it.

Just state that you didn't realize that there was a significant personal cost involved with this event and that you've not budgeted for it.

You can bet that other employees will also decline when they learn that they have to pay to attend a company social event, and they won't be happy about the fact.

Comment: *"Be honest about it" but focus on the **budget** issue and don't let them gossip and/or dig around your personal finance, it is none of their business. If mishandled, you can pass off as "cheap", and this is not the intent. But this might be a good question for the IPS stack.

Comment: Additionally, if management have responses like this from several people they will realise this is an issue and may organise events differently in the future. But they won't know if everyone suffers in silence.

Comment: From experience, people get very vocal about having to spend their own money for things like this - there’s bound to be a fair bit of backlash against the organisers.

Comment: I'd even leave out the "haven't budgeted for it" part, as that gives the impression that you're hard up.  (Even if true, you probably don't want people thinking that.)  Just say that whatever enjoyment you'd get just isn't worth the cost.  It's like inviting me to (pay for) say an  expensive wine tasting: sure, I can afford it, but I can't really tell the difference between them and the stuff I get in a cardboard box at the supermarket - and when I can, I generally like the box stuff better  :-)

Comment: I agree with @jamesqf, there must be some reason OP wants to avoid being direct, or else I wouldn't expect this question to be necessary

Comment: A potential issue I see with this answer is that it sounds like OP doesn't actually want to go.  Particularly if it's a smaller company, they might take steps to remove the stated objection - 'Oh, it's okay, you can just come after dinner is served.  Don't worry about the money, just come out...' or similar.  If you are willing to do, if the cost was reduced or removed, then it's great.  But if they make special accommodations and you don't go it will be perceived as far more rude than if you just didn't go.

Comment: @Snow that comment is an excellent bit of analysis that you should probably include in your answer.

Comment: @DoritoStyle Probably OP is uncomfortable or inexperienced confronting their boss and is looking for the most tactful/least confrontation way to go about it.

Comment: @Mindwin I'd take it a step further: focus on the **cost** issue (which affects everyone going and which the company is mostly in control of) as opposed to the budget issue (which affects only OP and only OP is responsible for). The trick, of course, is not coming off accusatory, but the less OP takes responsibility for, the better.

Comment: @LastStar007 agreed, that's why I think the nature of the question refutes this answer a bit.

Answer (score 42):

Any activity that you have to pay for, or takes place outside of normal work hours is by definition optional. When it falls into both categories, the organizers should realize the many will decide not to go.

In your question you give two valid reasons: It is out of your budget, and your ill Mom takes up your free time. Don't talk about being forced to attend, this is not the time to talk about that.

The biggest issue about declining is the fact that it is only a few days away, and some of those costs may be locked in, and the share of everybody may have been announced. By deciding now to cancel, the locked in costs have to be covered by somebody.

You have to determine who you should communicate this to, and the best way to approach them. Is it by email, phone, or was there a electronic invitation? Also your approach you use is determine by did originally say yes, or were you a maybe.

The approach is to be polite, and apologize. Explain that you will not be able to spare the time this weekend, and that it is outside your budget. Apologize again. Remember the person you are talking to may not be the one who made the decision regarding costs, their only role may have been to process the RSVPs.

Comment: Didn't consider if things were already planned with costs. Great response

Comment: Great point. Luckily I declined before they plan/purchase anything.

Comment: "*is by definition optional*" it should be, but isn't. In the US it's perfectly legal for an employer to mandate attendance at events outside work hours and even charge people for it.

Comment: @Lilienthal I'm pretty sure that's not true. For hourly ('non-exempt' [from overtime laws]) employees, a required event would be something for which they would need to be paid. For salaried ('exempt') employees tho, they probably *could* be required to attend an event, but not *necessarily* require to pay to do so (e.g. because of potential employment contracts or whatnot).

Comment: @Lilienthal - Please link to that law.

Comment: Agree with Kenny, _in_theory_ it is illegal.  But in practice, if you cross the boss, he/she can easily figure out a legal excuse to explain firing you or a legal explanation for an unpleasant assignment.

Comment: @KennyEvitt I didn't say they wouldn't be required to pay people for it (if non-exempt), that's an entirely different topic. I'm merely stating the simple fact that in the US an employer can ask an employee to do pretty much anything that isn't explicitly illegal or covered by employment laws forbidding it (e.g. OSHA). That's what you get when you have no or minimal employee protection laws. And that's why I can't link to "that law" because no law is required to make this sort of thing possible. It's the absence of a law prohibiting it that means an employer can do this. The employee can quit.

Comment: I have to agree with @Lilienthal. In the US, employers have freedom to mandate anything outside the scope of federal/state laws. Most of the time though, employers will cover expenses for business function or travel but they might not cover everything.

Comment: @Lilienthal In the context of this question and answer, your comment was misleading as it implied that employers can mandate attendance *without pay*. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I agree with @KennyEvitt, if an organization was paying employees to attend an event, then i can't imagine a likely scenario that would have employees paying to host the event.

Comment: @Lilienthal, additionally, and sorry to nitpick, but there is no "absense of law" about compensation for *mandatory work-related events* in the case of non-except salary & hourly employees, that is well-established federal law.

Comment: https://www.dol.gov/whd/regs/compliance/whdfs22.pdf#page=2
"Attendance at lectures, meetings, training programs and similar
activities need not be counted as working time only if four criteria are met, namely: it is outside normal hours, it
is **voluntary, not job related**, and no other work is concurrently performed. "

Comment: @Lilienthal : "I didn't say they wouldn't be required to pay people"... actually, what you said was worse: "even charge people for it".

Comment: @Ramhound: "Please link to that law" ["for an employer to mandate"...]?  Laws are usually more prone to identify prohibited activity, not specifically written to identify legal activity.  Even if Lilienthal were right, I would not expect such a law necessarily exists (nor is needed)

Comment: Lilienthal indicated that in the USA an employer can mandate attendance and require an employee to pay to attend an event outside of their duty location. Which is basically saying they can force an employee to pay their employer to come to work.  Salvery is illegal, being required to come to work (for free), is illegal in the USA (its called slavery).  If you are required to attend something, you must be paid for it, something cannot be optional and be required....

Comment: @Ramhound et al: Please don't misconstrue what I said and read up on *US* employment law. Employers can legally pass off any and all costs to their employees. The only thing they can't do is breach minimum salary laws or not pay those who are hourly or non-exempt for any hours worked. I didn't specify this outright because it should have gone without being said to anyone familiar with US law...

Comment: @Lilienthal "Employers can legally pass off any and all costs to their employees. "  Source needed.  

Show an example of where an employer has a mandatory, out of normal work hours event, and requires employees to pay to attend?

Comment: @Lilienthal No, employers [***may not*** "pass off any and all costs to their employees"](https://www.dol.gov/whd/opinion/FLSA/2006/2006_03_10_07_FLSA.htm), only costs that directly benefit the employee rather than the employer (things like charging employees for eating at the company cantina), though that prohibition is apparently not well known and many employers may be getting away with doing this.

Comment: @Lilienthal for a normally rational contributor, you seem to have a bone to pick on this issue which is clouding your ability to judge your own words. I don't mean this as an attack, so hopefully it can help you decide to maybe recuse from this topic?

Comment: @DoritoStyle Notice how I haven't responded since my last comment four days ago... I don't have a bone to pick here but having to argue US laws with those coming from a EU perspective is certainly tiresome. I've pointed out the issues with this topic and have no plans to respond to anything else said here.

Comment: @Lilienthal a bit late to the discussion, but almost everyone disagreeing with you who has their location in their profile is in the USA

Answer (score 15):

Any point in time at which you learn some new material fact about the event, is a new point at which it's legit to decline. So if they announced the event six months ago, but told you only a few days in advance that it'd cost (a lot!!) then that's a point in which you can certainly decide to decline.

I agree with the above answers, that you should politely make it clear that it's about the money, and not make up some sick-aunt excuse. If they push back that they committed resources based on your earlier positive response, then the answer should be along the lines of "Sorry to hear that, Boss, but I only learned yesterday that there would be a cost, and it's just not something that's in my budget right now."

It is deeply manipulative of this workplace to set you and your co-workers up like this, and you have every right to be offended: you are the victim here, not them (assuming you've told us the full story). In fact as you discuss it with them, consider using phrases like "I understand your difficult position" and "I'm sad to hear that" instead of "sorry".

You may need to start making long-term plans about your commitment to this outfit.

Answer (score 7):

You could literally say ***because the cost is too high***.

If they press, you can continue ***"well, it's over an entire day's worth of my pay"***.

The key here is that the problem is with the **event**, not with **you**. Your budget/finances are **NOT** the problem, so you need to prevent people from suggesting that the problem is on your end.

If they really *press* (which would be rude, but you never know), you can elaborate by pointing out that a day's worth of work would be a high cost to pay even  if you made $1,000,000/day, but if they keep pressing on this point, you might have to show some disgust at their questions and move on.

Answer (score 6):

I am retired. I encountered similar situations many times throughout my career life. Besides the expense, I am an introvert person. When the social event could cost me close to one day salary or more, I usually said

> Sorry, I cannot afford to it unless I am getting a good pay raise.

Half joking and half serious.

It worked in most cases. One of the few times it failed was because the boss said "Okay, I'll give you a good raise".

I never got pay raise from him because he was promoted to another division a few months later and unable to do PIP with me.

Comment: Sometimes humor is processed by people that don't (or can't) take things in the manner they were intended.  I'd rephrase your comment for the broader audience of the humor-impaired "Sorry, I cannot afford it unless the company is willing to cover the expense."

Answer (score 3):

I'm from Germany and we sometimes have a concept that I think is relevant here *(unfortunately I don't know the translation, and I expect it to be highly idiomatic - @everyone please help).*

The **Betriebsschwein** (Schwein = pig = here bad colleague) or **Arsch vom Dienst** (literally: asshole-on-duty).

The idea here is to have someone taking the *role* of the bad guy who breaks the social harmony in order to put an example. In situations like the one you describe, the Betriebsschwein does this and takes the shame in order to make sure that people in a weaker position - who may not dare to ask for what is actually their right - do get the possibility to execute their rights without the social strain of seeing (or fearing) their weakness exposed.*

Now, it seems to me that your company right now needs such a Betriebsschwein who points out that the proposed contributions are far outside the sensible range (for many?/some? employees) and that therefore he/she will not participate (to state an example).

Whether this role is one *you* can take in the present situation, is something you can decide only for yourself:

- Is your standing in the firm good enough to warrant this?
  (My personal experience is that I *gained* respect by both peers and supervisors by taking such positions. It is important, though, to do this from a position of personal integrity, and not become the troublemaker who just seeks an occasion)
- It's always difficult to do this exactly for those who need it most (i.e. are in those weak positions). This is known, and it is perfectly fine to analyse the personal situation and find that right now is not the occasion where you can do anything.
- Practically speaking: it is easiest to take this role for someone who doesn't have the problem in question (but does recognize it).
  This may be you in the sense that due to your budgeting, you may actually be much less hard up than many of your colleagues.
- The Betriebsschwein is a strong position that is defending the weak. Knowing and pointing this out mentally and emotionally makes it considerably easier for the Betriebsschwein (after all, this is a conflict situation, where the Betriebsschwein goes for fight instead of flight).

  E.g. by saying: this is too much, and it is very inconsiderate. How, for example, is someone with low wages (e.g., a janitor, secretary, ...) or someone who has to feed a large family going to manage this in a financially healthy way? And really, anyone here could be in such a situation without us knowing this - you never know (and it's none of our business) whom people have to support.

  Over here (as you know, Germans are <strike>rude</strike> blunt and outspoken), I personally would maybe go as far as saying that "certainly everyone is entitled to use their own money as they like - but only [insert culturally *just* acceptable term for bad guy here] make/tempt others who *should* keep inside a tight budget to spend."**
- People give varying advise here about whether it is wise to mention your budgeting, or whether this will start gossip about your financial position. Of course, also in this respect it is much easier to not care if the budgeting already got you into a financially healthy position.

  - Take an honest estimate of your finances (as you are budgeting I'm sure you know this) and compare your position with relevant statistical data. You may be surprised to find that your budgeting already got you ahead of your average peer (do not forget to take into account your age).
  - Depending on your current financial position, your history and age, at some point you'll hopefully reach the position where you can say: "I know this, I've *been* there.". Even if you decide that you are not yet in the position to take the Betriebsschwein role, at that point it should become easy to do so (unless you meanwhile forget how it was).
- You don't need to always be the Betriebsschwein. But it does become easier with experience ;-), and as this is labeled 'company-culture' once this is established as a role, others may be taking this role in other situations.

---

* We also use the same term for a different type of situation: E.g. I once met a bus driver who did scout-group-like holiday camp tours. They'd sometimes give a ride to, say, a colleague's kid till some place along the route and that kid was told to be the Betriebsschwein: When that kid was about to get off, they'd enact misbehaviour were apparently "thrown out". The bus driver said this works miracles with adolescents that are used to not having to face any really hard consequences...

** And as we are talking here about the management of a business: I'd expect *businessmen* to be able to keep finances in a healthy shape. This includes personal finances. (I know there are more than enough counter examples - but this is about the role model.) And I expect a *manager* to be able to apply this to their employees in the sense that they should not unnecessarily hinder their employee's possibilities and actually responsibilities in this respect.
If someone's work is worth only a low wage to the company that's one thing. But then *invading* their presumably already strained finances by demanding a social event contribution of several working *hours* (not even to speak of days) is a completely different category.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, be honest. Also, be polite and professional. However,  I think it best that you ***talk about the expense***, and ***avoid mentioning your budget***.

Although you seem ambivalent about attending otherwise, it seems you want to make it clear that the main reason you're not going is the cost is simply too high. If you mention that it's not in your budget, it may make you look bad (for not budgeting better), and they might even say that you should put a little more away so that you can afford the next event.

Thus I recommend saying something along the lines of:

> Sorry, but the cost is too much for me.

Generally, I would recommend that you leave it at that. Hopefully, an answer like this will get your boss to consider picking up (more of) the expenses for any future social activities. That's even more likely if several people make similar statements.

The one risk with the above recommendation is that management might decide to cover the expenses, or maybe your boss would pay your share. If you would still want to avoid the event even if that happens, then I suggest that you talk about taking care of your Mom first, especially if it is already known that you do that. If that's the case, an answer like the following would probably be better.

> As you know, I need to help my Mom out quite often, and she needs help that day. However, even if I weren't already committed to helping her, I wouldn't be able to go, unfortunately, because the cost is too much for me.

Comment: I agree with this. Saying you didn't budget for it, means that in the future, if they give you more notice you'd likely go, which probably isn't true.

Answer (score 1):

This is just my personal take on this. I haven't been working for very long at all (Aged 18, working 8-9 months).

Putting it straight forward: You do not have to worry about declining a social event. You are not required to attend any social events. Sure it's sad to see you won't come but it's not like you'll be seen as a bad person and you won't have your pay docked the next morning.

For what to reply with, you did say:

> At first I accepted the invitation (**although I wasn't at all into it**)

So it would be acceptable to say something like

> I didn't feel like going to the event because it isn't my thing / cup of tea / analogy to say you don't like it as much as other things

If it was pricing alone which put you off you can reply with something like:

> I haven't budgeted properly for the event so I didn't want to pay.

And from my own knowledge and if I said something like that, I wouldn't be frowned upon in the working environment.

I'm also sure that these sort of questions aren't linked to the work environment at all. They won't effect work and they won't effect relationships. As I see from other answers, politeness is also key. My final "full" response from looking at other answers would be something like:

> I'm sorry about not coming to the social event this weekend but I couldn't afford to go because I didn't realise it had a cost and I didn't budget for it.

First answer here. Feedback is great. I hope my response helps at all in this case.

Comment: `Putting it straight forward: You do not have to worry about declining a social event.` That's not _always_ true; I've been working a long time and I can definitely say that in some companies "joining in" on the social side is _very_ important to one's career. Fortunately I'm not in that situation now but I have been in the past.

Comment: Ah... Guess it depends on the company then. It can be understandable that joining in with a social event can boost your own image too but it's rather do you take that image along with you inside work. I think I got lucky but thanks for the heads up

Comment: Not just for social events. For all kinds of contributions that employees go around asking for money, just decline if you don't feel like contributing. I've lost a lot of money to unnecessary contributions. Not because the contribution went for a waste, but because these 'collectors' were rude and took the contribution for granted. It's never worth it. http://nrecursions.blogspot.in/2015/12/donating-to-every-cause-is-impractical.html

Comment: @Nav It depends on what they're asking for and how much. Declining a few bucks for a going-away present for a popular employee might make you look like a scrooge. On the other hand, you shouldn't feel obligated to buy someone's kid's Girl Scout cookies.

Comment: I didn't go to the company Christmas party one year, and shortly after was moved to a team on a project that was far more onerous than the project I'd been working on.  I'm not saying the two are necessarily connected, but it got me thinking.

Answer (score 1):

## Be honest, but consider the easy way out

It may be very simple:

If you now ensure that you have other obligations on that day, you can mention them when people ask whether you may join.

Unless they really dig, or focus on the causality, you can avoid awkwardness without a single lie.

---

If this does not help, you still do not need to lie. You can then still decide to tell the full (more personal) story, or simply not answer their questions.

## Alternately: displace the focus

What I would personally do in your situation is not to say that my finances cannot not support the event, but that they should not. It can be as simple as:

> I believe company events should be sponsored (more).

That way you do get the point across that your reason is purely financial, but may reduce the (potentially undesirable) impact on your own image.

Note that this response does invite people to challenge your response. So consider in advance what arguments you want to use, and think of how far you want to go in a discussion. Note that the fact that you make this statement (and the arguments that you use to support it) will likely impact your image in a way as well.

Comment: I disagree with your alternative suggestion. That looks like you're refusing to attend a social event because you think it's more important to make a political point ("Events should be arranged in this particular way") than to socialize with your colleagues. I think that has a terrible impact on your image. And suppose there's another event in the future that costs twice as much but the company covers half the cost so the amount the employees have to pay is the same as they're paying for this event. The asker still can't afford to go, even though their political request has been met.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Perhaps it depends on the culture, but where I am from it is indeed very common that employers cover (all) the costs of social event **which are organized by the company**. (For something like a ski trip a contribution is of course more common) Thus I would definitely make a point out of it, not in the least because this is the companies first attempt and they will be most sensitive to feedback. -- If there is a future event which is sponsored, but still not sponsored enough, the argument still holds.

Comment: Of course there's an expectation that company events be paid for, or at least subsidized, but that doesn't override what I said. If you say "I'm not going because it should be subsidized more" this will be interpreted as you saying that your protest is more important than socializing with your colleagues. If you say you can't go, you can't go. If you _don't_ say you can't go, it sounds like you could go, but you've decided not to.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Again an interesing cultural/personal point. It is indeed a choice whether you would rather depict your self as being too poor for an event, or as someone who chooses not to go. -- I did try to address this by mentioning the image, but have updated the answer to mention it a bit more explicitly.

Comment: @DavidRicherby you make the assumption that anything seeming political should be avoid, but I retort that office politics are unavoidable, and when it affects your income then there is very little reason to abstain. Sure, it might affect your image, but any person that judges you negatively for being reasonably financially prudent is not to be regarded IMO.

Comment: @DoritoStyle If the issue is your income, don't pretend that your issue is the level of subsidy. I would hope that somebody wouldn't be judged for declining because they couldn't afford to attend. My whole point is that saying "I'm not going because I can't afford it" is _very_ different from saying "I'm not going because I believe our employer should subsidize it more."

Comment: @DavidRicherby I'm not sure how that relates back to the point about 'seeming political', but the discussion is dragging on a bit, let me know if you think we should continue and i'll make a chat room.

Comment: In my culture, demanding "company events should be sponsored (more)." sounds rather bad. Solution here: event shouldn't be crazy expensive (company can and does sponsor btw.). For a small company doing their first social event ever, it would be more like "everyone brings something", management/company covers beer, water, juice and the rent for the BBQ place or table+bench sets to put on the lawn. Oh, and our tax law says: everything > 110€/attending employee/year is wage and subject to income tax etc.. Summer + Xmas party with avg. 2 persons/employee attending => 25-30 €/employee.

Answer (score 0):

**"I have a conflict."**  Having had multiple experiences of the same or similar, this has ALWAYS worked for me.

- *Less is best.* - A person of few words rarely struggles to honor integrity.
- *Mind YOUR mind.* - What others assume of you, what you say, or what you do is none of your business.

***If pressed,...*** redirect by asking a question or finding something in their question or comment with which to agree.

- *Actual Example 1* - COWORKER: A schedule conflict, you mean? ME: Why do you ask? COWORKER: Just wondered. ME: Oh, okay. (pause) So, did you see the game last night? That last inning was intense!
- *Actual Example 2* - BOSS: Well, I'm sorry to see you backed out. Team-building is important. ME: I absolutely agree! I hope to not
  have a conflict next time. Maybe we could do a potluck, watch the
  game together... something laid back like that. (pause) Hope the
  event goes well. Good chatting with you. Better get back to work. BOSS: Yes, do that. We'll miss you. ME: Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Be honest. One reason that I don't believe has been touched upon is this:

There might have been discussions about whether going with a more expensive event, and asking employees to pick up the costs, would force workers to decline and be excluded.  The fact is, it ***is*** the cost that is making you decline.  Let them know that. Perhaps in the future they will opt for smaller, simpler, less expensive but more inclusive events when planning.

A simple -

> Unfortunately, the cost-sharing is out of my budget range for a social event like this.

should suffice. If they want to pry further and find out what your personal "squeal point" is, financially, simply state that this is personal information, as well as situational, and you decline to share it.